# MVC3 AD Role based authorization for JQGrid Edit link

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, jqgrid, active-directory

I am very new to JQgrid and mvc3 . I have a very basic jQgrid with edit functionality.

I want to disable edit link in jqgrid.navgrid  for certain user (autheticated by AD) when JqGrid load and enable it for other user which has diffewrent roles.

I am able to restrict user from editing the grid data but that's not sufficient .I want user not to even see that editable link in JqGrid .

Here is the JqGrid which  I have in my view( index.cshtml):

```
 jQuery(document).ready(function () {
             jQuery('#list').jqGrid({
             colNames: ['id', 'CountryCode','Node','EligFactor'],
             colModel: [
                       { name: 'id', index: 'id', width: 150, height: 100, align: 'left' },
                       { name: 'CountryCode', index: 'CountryCode', width: 150, align: 'left' },
                       {name: 'Node', index: 'Node', width: 150, height: 100, align: 'left' },
                       {name: 'EligFactor', index: 'EligFactor', width: 150, height: 100, align: 'left', editable: true, edittype: 'text' }
                       ],
            url: '@Url.Action("DynamicGridData")',
            datatype: 'json',
            mtype: 'POST',
            pager: jQuery('#pager'),
            rowNum: 10,
            rowList: [5, 10, 15, 20, 25],
            sortname: 'Id',
            sortorder: "asc",
            viewrecords: true,
            imgpath: '',
            caption: 'Eligibility Factor Grid',
            imgpath: '/Content/images',
            height: '210px'

             }).navGrid('#pager', { edit: true, add: false, del: false, search: false, refresh: true },
                 { url: '@Url.Action("EditRecord")', closeAfterEdit: true },
                 {},

                 {});
         });
```

2,   Here is the edit method in controller which is being used when user try to edit the grid data :

```
     [Authorize(Roles=@"MyDomain\SecurityLists\User1")]
        public ActionResult EditRecord(int id, string eligFactor)
        {
            bool success = false;
            var context = new EligibilityFactorDataContext();
            EligibilityControl eg = context.EligibilityControls.Single(p => p.id == id);

            eg.EligFactor = Convert.ToSingle(eligFactor);

            try
            {
                context.SubmitChanges();
                success = true;
                return Json(success);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                success = false;
                return Json(success);
                            }

        }
```

can someone pl. help me to achieve this . very appreciated !

```
var context = new EligibilityFactorDataContext();


            var isAuth = true;
            int pageIndex = Convert.ToInt32(page) - 1;
            int pageSize = rows;
            int totalRecords = context.EligibilityControls.Count();
            int totalPages = (int)Math.Ceiling((float)totalRecords / (float)pageSize);
            var eligibilitycontrols = context.EligibilityControls.OrderBy(sidx + " " + sord).Skip(pageIndex * pageSize).Take(pageSize);
            var jsonData = new
            {
              total = totalPages,
              page =   page,
              records = totalRecords,
              userdata = isAuth,
              rows = (
                      from eligibilitycontrol in eligibilitycontrols
                      select new
                      {
                        id = eligibilitycontrol.id,
                        cell = new string[]  {
                                               eligibilitycontrol.id.ToString() ,
                                               eligibilitycontrol.CountryCode, 
                                               eligibilitycontrol.Node.ToString(), 
                                              Convert.ToSingle(eligibilitycontrol.EligFactor).ToString()}

                                             }).ToArray()
             };
          return Json(jsonData);
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a check if the user is authenticated and pass a bool in your viewmodel to your view if the user is authenticated or not and modify the nav pager based on this.

Ex

```
var userIsAuth = '@Model.UserIsAuth' == 'true';
jQuery('#list').jqGrid().navGrid('#pager', { edit: (userIsAuth ? true : false), add: false, del: false, search: false, refresh: true },
      { url: '@Url.Action("EditRecord")', closeAfterEdit: true },
      {},    
      {});
```

So in the controller you need to define the UserData in a similar manner Ex

```
 userdata = new {ExampleName = ExampleValue},
```

Then in your loadComplete: function()

```
var myPassedUserData = $(this).getGridParam('userData');
var ExampleVariable = myPassedUserData.ExampleName
```

Edit- Use Ternary operation to simplify the code. Possibly the `url:` property could also be disabled via the userIsAuth bool.

Comment: Mark, thanks for your comment.first thing , I don't have Jqgrid() like that ..I have bunch of param:value inside that ..and if I use like you mentioned..its lot of cods repeat..doesn't seem like nice way to do it ..and even I am not sure how to pass that paramter from my controller.. I tried to put something like this in my DynamicGridData mehtod :

Comment: I added DynamicGridData in my actual question

Comment: I don't understand what you mean that you don't have a jQgrid() like that? All I did above was to define out the building of the navigation area separate from where you declare the grid itself.  You could easily simplify the above code into one statement with ternary operators but I wanted to keep it explicit.  If you don't know how to pass a bool to your View, I guess you could pass it via Userdata in your jQgrid data.

Comment: Hi mark,i am sorry but it seems i am doing something wrong. i added userdata:isAuth in method which called when grid loads ( dynamic grid data ). also i added  loadComplete: function(){var isAuth = jQuery("#list").getGridParam('userData')} . but i am getting isAuth is undefined . do i need to defind isAuth parameter somewhere else. thanks for your help !